# Connect Android app to Heroku db

Tags: android, heroku, parse-platform

I recently created an iOS app using Heroku as the backend server.  I want to be able to create the same app in Android using the same information in Heroku.

Any ideas as to how i can do this? I have researched and i see a lot about creating an API (which i am new to android and not sure how to do this).

I downloaded the Parse Starter Project and in the StarterApplication.java, according to Parse.com, you place the appId and key in the Parse.initialize() but what about the server information.  Confused!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With parse server you initialize like this:

```
Parse.initialize(new Parse.Configuration.Builder(context)
                .applicationId(appId)
                .clientKey(null)
                .server(serverUrl)
                .build());
```

Not sure if you need the `clientKey(null)` part, I'd try without that first.